# Получение данных со страницы Instagram

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Нужно парсить данные со страницы пользователя, по его желанию. По возможности, поддерживать актуальность данных в течение дня. 
Данные в данном случае - это товары, которые продает пользователь (магазин). 
Спарсенные данные будут использоваться для их аналитики, трансформации в другие сущности и т.п. для увеличения конверсии продаж и удобства ведения бизнеса.

Как я понимаю, на функции парсинга страниц есть ограничения.

Учитывается ли тот момент, что приложение работает только по соглашению пользователя и только с его страницей, и для его блага? Речи о массовом парсинге только в интересах стороннего приложения не идет. 
Спасибо!

Comment: Конкретизируйте что подразумевается под "...по его желанию." и "приложение работает только по соглашению пользователя..."? Кем "...учитывается ли тот момент...."?

Comment: "по его желанию" - имеется ввиду что пользователь конкретно сам "что-то нажимает" и только после этого приложение, так сказать, вступает в работу. По поводу "...учитывается ли тот момент...." - инстаграм как к такому относится? Банят за такое?

Answer (score 1):

Соцсети обычно имеют ограничение на количество подключений(запросов) с одного IP, иногда ограничение могут ставить разное на разные локали. Если запрашивать и парсить JSON - то в условиях использования будет четко все расписано [(Например в API)](https://www.instagram.com/developer/). Если это предполагает какую-то комерческую деятельность(страничка с продажей товара/услуги, реклама и. др.) - то тем более все должно прописываться в соглашении между сайтом и комерсантом. Вам стоит обратиться к [тех-поддержке](https://help.instagram.com/) инстаграма, дабы Вас случайно не дизинформировали устаревшей информацией люди которые не имеют прямого отношения к тех-поддержке инстаграма.

Comment: Спасибо! Поизучаю еще раз документацию)